# how to predict value for future date in r

Tags: r, date, machine-learning, prediction

sample data ->

```
> tail(India_df)
          date confirmed deaths recovered
98  2020-04-28     31324   1008      7747
99  2020-04-29     33062   1079      8437
100 2020-04-30     34863   1154      9068
101 2020-05-01     37257   1223     10007
102 2020-05-02     39699   1323     10819
103 2020-05-03     42505   1391     11775
```

i want to predict that how many confirmed cases will be there on some future date like -> "2020-05-05"

i am using polynomial regression to fit the model ->

```
fit2 = lm(confirmed~poly(date,6))
```

i tried using this ->

```
new <- data.frame(pred_dates <- as.Date(c("2020-05-05","2020-05-06")))
predict.lm(fit2,new,interval = "confidence")
```

but it is showing this error ->

```
'newdata' had 2 rows but variables found have 103 rows
```

Comment: Is that `lm(...)` *ignoring* `India_df`, or is the code you're showing us not the same as what you are using?

Comment: i used `attach(India_df)` so i am uing column names directly , that's why..

Comment: (In my opinion, any tutorial/lesson/class that suggests the use of `attach` should just stop. I cannot think of one situation where it is anything except a bad crutch, and the risks/consequences of using it outweigh any convenience it may give.) Glad you got the help you needed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `data` argument in `lm`, and use the same names of the predictors in the new dataframe:

```
fit2 <- lm(confirmed ~ poly(date,6), data = India_df)

new <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2020-05-05","2020-05-06")))

predict(fit2, new, interval = "confidence")
```